# Measuring relative speeds in SR

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light

Suppose I have a galactic ruler spanned from earth to Alpha Centauri. With marked units, so one can read off the distance starting with 0 at earth until 4 light-years at Alpha Centauri.

Now according to relativity, if I fly with my spaceship at 97% of the speed of light from earth to Alpha Centauri this will only take about 1 year.
At first glance, this would seem I am going 4 lightyears within a year to contradict the no faster than light travel. However, this is explained by length contraction. So this means basically that from my frame of reference I cannot trust the hatch marks of the ruler at all.

This brings me to my question:
How would I even measure the relative speed to the ruler if I cannot trust these lengths? The same goes for a person on earth?

Both parties would measure the same relative speed as can be computed! from SR. But how would we measure it?

The fact that both parties measure the same value for the relative speed - is this an assumption that goes into deriving SR or is it a consequence as well?

Comment: It is an important point. The usual way to check its own velocity, by using marks with known length and a clock, is an approximation valid for low speeds.

Comment: If all you can see is a ruler moving past you, and you don't know how far apart the marks are, you can't tell how fast the ruler is moving.  This is equally true in a Newtonian world and in a relativistic world.  If you want to know how fast the ruler is moving, you need some additional observations, and the sort of additional observations you need are the same in both worlds.  The exact interpretation of those observations might depend on the underlying physics, but the basic problem is really not at all about relativity.

Comment: Curiously, even though 4 people answered you, I have no idea what you are asking. It seems to me, you are strangely and carelessly jumping between the two frames.  Are you asking how can you measure the speed which would observer at Earth measure, when he measures your speed? Seems kind of nonsensical. You can either measure the thing, at which case you need to use Earths apparatus (i.e. the ruler at rest wrt Earth), or you can compute what would the Earth observer measure from results of some of your own measurements (i.e. ruler at rest wrt you). But you cannot measure another measurement.

Answer (score 4):

Usually the easiest way to measure speed is with Doppler radar. For an inertial observer this gives the same velocity as you would get with a system of rods at rest and synchronized clocks.

Answer (score 2):

You send a light signal forwards towards a particular mark on the giant ruler at time, say, $t_1$ seconds. At  $t_2$ seconds you see the mark illuminated by your light flash. So the round trip there and back took $t_2-t_1$ .
The flashes take the same time on each leg because you are stationary, so you know the mark was $c(t_2-t_1)/2$ metres away at time $(t_2+t_1)/2$.

Wait a short but arbitrary time to $t_3$, then send another flash to the same mark, and it comes back at  $t_4$. Now you have a second distance measurement, $c(t_4-t_3)/2$, presumably shorter than the first as the mark is moving towards you, at a later time $(t_4+t_3)/2$.  The ratio of the differences gives you the velocity.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that to an observer on earth, at rest with respect to the ruler, you pass mark $x_1$ at time $t_1$ and mark $x_2$ at time $t_2$. So he measures you speed as ($x_2$-$x_1$)/($t_2$-$t_1$).

Let's say you do the same with the same two marks. So you would pass $x_1'$ at time $t_1'$ and $x_2'$ and time $t_2'$ and measure your speed relative to the ruler as ($x_2'$-$x_1'$)/($t_2'$-$t_1'$).

As the ruler is at rest in the earth's frame of reference, as you say it's length is contracted in your moving frame. So ($x_2'$-$x_1'$) = ($x_2$-$x_1$)/$\gamma$. But we have to also take account of time dilation. Your time measurement, ($t_2'$-$t_1'$), is a proper time interval as your clock is at rest in your frame of reference. So we have ($t_2'$-$t_1'$) = ($t_2$-$t_1$)/$\gamma$.

As a result, ($x_2'$-$x_1'$)/($t_2'$-$t_1'$) will equal ($x_2$-$x_1$)/($t_2$-$t_1$) and both you and the earth observer will measure the same relative speed.

Here $\gamma$ is the usual $1/\sqrt(1-v^2/c^2)$.