# At what speed will the dilated time be twice the time on earth

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, time-dilation

At what speed will the dilated time be twice the time on earth?

All my calculations using $$t'=\frac{t}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$$ have given me strange results.

Is this even possible. If not, why?

Comment: Hello! I have edited your question using MathJax (LaTeX) math typesetting. For future questions, you can refer to [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Comment: *All my calculations … have given me strange results.* You didn’t show any of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Time *dilation*" means that the "dilated time" $t$ will be smaller than $t'$. This is because the Lorentz factor $$\gamma=\frac1{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}\tag{1}$$ is always larger than one. In other words, the time that an observer in a moving frame of reference measures is greater than the time that the "stationary" observer measures.

One usually uses $t'$ for the time that the moving observer measures; then we have $$t'=\frac{t}{\gamma}\tag{2}$$

You used the variables the other way around which is fine, but one should not get confused. See also [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/600341/).

So if you want to be the "dilated time", which I assume is the time measured in the moving frame of reference, to be larger than the time that the stationary observer measures, this is not possible.

If you want $t=2t'$ (be careful: I use the variables here as I explained above, i.e. the other way around as you), i.e. the "dilated time" to be half of the "stationary time", you can solve equation $(2)$ for $v$.